# Equivariant line bundles and connections

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-cohomology

Equivariant line bundle isomorphism classes are classified by the equivariant cohomology group $H^2_{P}(X;\mathbb{Z})$ and let us take $P$ to be finite abelian and $X$ a finite dimensional CW-complex to simplify matters.

I was wondering how to understand these classes in terms of the connection $A$ of the associated $U(1)$-bundle. I know of some examples where it is not the curvature $F_{A}$ but the connection $A$ itself integrated over a subregion (or boundary of said subregion) fixed under the $P$-action to obtain some of these classes.

Is there a general procedure to describe any given class in terms of an integral of the connection $A$ or its curvature $F_{A}$ over some subregion of $X$ and how does this region relate to the $P$-action?

Thanks for reading

Comment: If you're trying to get the class by integrating anything, you will presumably be working in $H^2_P (X, \mathbb R)$. If $P$ is finite, then this is just the $P$-invariants of the usual cohomology of $\mathbb R$, since the characteristic zero representation theory of finite groups is semisimple, so you just want to integrate the connection normally.

Comment: Dear Will, no, in fact torsion invariants are most of the interesting classes and one can obtain torsion integrating i.e. see [Freed's discussion](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-107/issue-3/Determinants-torsion-and-strings/cmp/1104116145.full) about torsion and equation (3.9).